# How to populate a drop down list, using a web service in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-services

I am teaching myself how to do this for a job I won't get but I need to learn it for future interviews.  I've searched for tutorials specifically for populating a drop down list but coming up empty.  I could populate with a DB but using a web service is over my head.

I have not had any experience with web services before so maybe I should start there?  I have been using ASP.NET MVC-5 for almost a year now to get practice, so I am familiar with the technology.  Any guidance on what steps I should take to finish the drop down list would be greatly appreciated.  So links to tutorials or descriptions....

Comment: How about you post some actual code so we can guide you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually pretty straight forward. You can view this exact scenario with detailed explanation at following URL : [Binding a Drop down list to web service in ASP.Net](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Populate-Bind-DropDownList-using-JavaScript-and-ASP.Net-AJAX.aspx).

If you don't understand something there, you are welcome to ask me here.

Comment: Awesome, exactly the kind of explanation I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to do it on windows forms..

```
private void btnDisplay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
    ServiceReference1.countrySoapClient X = new ServiceReference1.countrySoapClient("countrySoap");

    string Country;
    Country = X.GetCountries();

    XmlDocument AllCountries = new XmlDocument();
    AllCountries.LoadXml(Country);

    XmlNodeList ListOfCountries = AllCountries.SelectNodes("NewDataSet/Table");

    foreach(XmlNode y in ListOfCountries)
    {
        comboBox1.Items.Add(y.InnerText);
    }
}
```